# Checking if list contains numbers in R

Tags: r

I have a list:

```
list(c(1,2,3,4), c(3,2,6,8),c(6,4,3))
```

How would I be able to filter out for the list that contains 2 and 3 in each of the vectors? (They do not necessary have to be in descending/ ascending order)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Filter` like this:

```
L <- list(c(1,2,3,4), c(3,2,6,8), c(6,4,3))
Filter(function(x) all(2:3 %in% x), L)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 3 2 6 8
```

The above uses no packages but if we were to use `fn` from the gsubfn package it could be shortened to the following.  The formula is regarded as the specification of a function whose body is the right hand side and whose arguments are the free variables in the body, in this case just `x`.

```
library(gsubfn)

fn$Filter(~ all(2:3 %in% x), L)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are using `tidyverse`, one option is `keep` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
keep(lst, ~all(2:3 %in% .x))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 2 6 8
```